# Loading new JSON value using UI thread

Tags: android, json

I am facing problem while updating the new values fetched from json file after some interval (assume any either 5 second or any).I have developed this code and now I am stucked in this. When I run this code it shows the value after second run did not get updated the second time. I have implemented the handler but it is also not working here. I have used UI thread but I am facing problem again while using it.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
    String result = "";

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        a=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.a);
        b=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.b);
        c=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.c);

        Runnable hand = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
                task.execute("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/12345/feeds.json?results=1");
            }
        };

        new Thread(hand).start();
    }
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;

            } 
        @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Runnable handa = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    search(result);
                }
            };
            new Thread(handa).start();
        }

        public void search(String result){
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray weatherInfo = jsonObject.getJSONArray("feeds");

                JSONObject legsobject = weatherInfo.getJSONObject(0);
                final String field1 = legsobject.getString("field1");
                final String field2 = legsobject.getString("field2");
                final String field3 = legsobject.getString("field3");
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        a.setText(field1);
                        b.setText(field2);
                        c.setText(field3);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
}
```

Can any one guide because I am beginner in Android and try to do practice. Need your help. Your guidance would help me to learn more.

Comment: Just remove the thread from onPostExecute and add the logic in doInBackground itself and return JsonObject from doInBackground. FYI onPostExecute runs in UI/Main thread.

Comment: Also you don't need to to wrap your asyncTask in thread. FYI doInBackground run in background thread where as other method runs on main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
    String result = "";

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        a=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.a);
        b=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.b);
        c=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.c);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/12345/feeds.json?results=1");    
    }
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            } 
        @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            search(result);
        }

        public void search(String result){
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray weatherInfo = jsonObject.getJSONArray("feeds");

                JSONObject legsobject = weatherInfo.getJSONObject(0);
                final String field1 = legsobject.getString("field1");
                final String field2 = legsobject.getString("field2");
                final String field3 = legsobject.getString("field3");
                a.setText(field1);
                b.setText(field2);
                c.setText(field3);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me that where it is refreshing?

Comment: You have created mHandler object but did not pass it to asyntask or used it to consume the data. so I simply ignored handler object and removed threads in the code. So it'll work. alternatively, you can also pass handler to the async task and override handleMessage() method to refresh data

Comment: Sorry for asking again, Can you give me with an example of code.

Comment: Can you try running this and confirm if its working. Will explain the logic in detail

Comment: K let me check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177875/discussion-between-k132133-syed-arsalan-hussain-and-viswanath-kumar-sandu).